# Spark: reading local file, file should exist on all nodes?

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have a spark cluster with 2 machines say `mach-1` and `mach-2`.
I code on my local and then export it to JAR, and copy it to `mach-1`.
Then i run the code on `mach-1` using `spark-submit`.

The code tries to read a local file, which exists on `mach-1`.
It works well most of the time, but sometimes it gave me errors like `File does not exist`. So, i then copied the file to `mach-2` as well, and now the code works.

Similarly, while writing out the file to local, sometimes it worked when the output folder was only available on `mach-1`, but then it gave an error, and i created the output folder on `mach-2` as well. Now it creates the output in both `mach-1` and `mach-2` (some part in mach-1 and some part in mach-2).

Is this expected behavior? any pointers to texts explaining this.

P.S: i do not `collect` my RDDs before writing to local file (I do it in `foreach`). If i do that, the code works well with output folder only being present on `mach-1`.

Comment: and caching or persisting the RDD?  `.cache()` or `.persist()`, to make it available into the cluster

Comment: did not try caching or persisting ... i thought caching/persisting was required if we need to do multiple actions on the same RDD, without recomputing it every time. Also, i am not unhappy with this behavior, i just want to understand the how and why

Answer (score 2):

Your **input** data has to exist at every Node. You can achieve this by copy the data to the nodes, using NFS or HDFS.

For your **output** you can write to NFS or HDFS. Or you call collect(), but only do it, when your Dataset does fit into the Memory of the Driver. When it doesn't fit you should call rdd.toLocalIterator() or take(n).

Is it possible, that you run your code in Cluster Mode and not in Client Mode?